# Convert qmake into CMake

Tags: cmake, linker, static-libraries, qmake

I am new to CMake, but I used to use qmake. In my qmake, I have the following for adding a static library that is inside a folder called bin, inside the project folder:

```
QT -= gui
QT += core

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/bin/lib/ -lnanomsg
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/bin/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/bin/include
macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/bin/lib/libnanomsg.a
```

What is the corresponding CMake syntax?

I tried the following:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(./bin/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES($(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/bin/lib/)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(nanomsg)
```

but I get "can not specify target link library for nanomsg which is not build by this project" error. I built the library aligned from another project.

When I remove the `target_link_libraries`, I get linker errors for undefined symbols.

[Updated: here is the final working CMake file]

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(cmake-linkstatic VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Core)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core)
#this line is not needed any more
#INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/include)
add_library(nanomsg STATIC IMPORTED)
# Specify the nanomsg library's location and include directories.
set_target_properties(nanomsg PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/lib/libnanomsg.a"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/include"
)
# Define your executable CMake target.
# Link the nanomsg library to the executable target.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} nanomsg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a pre-built static library in your CMake, you can declare a `STATIC IMPORTED` CMake target:

```
add_library(nanomsg STATIC IMPORTED)

# Specify the nanomsg library's location and its include directories.
set_target_properties(nanomsg PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/lib/libnanomsg.a"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/include"
)
```

Here, we use the [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) variable to access the directory in which the current CMakeLists.txt file resides.

The [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) is used to link one library to *another* library (or executable), so the syntax should include at least two arguments. For example, if you want to link the static `nanomsg` library to an executable (such as `MyExecutable`), you could do it in CMake like this:

```
add_library(nanomsg STATIC IMPORTED)

# Specify the nanomsg library's location and include directories.
set_target_properties(nanomsg PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/lib/libnanomsg.a"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bin/include"
)

# Define your executable CMake target.
add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp)

# Link the nanomsg library to the executable target.
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable PUBLIC nanomsg)
```

Comment: I get undefined symbols for achitecture x86_64: _nn_bind, reference from ....

Comment: @DrlSherifOmran It is hard to suggest solutions for this without seeing the *specific* error, and knowing more information about your project. For example, it is unclear *how* you intend to use the `nanomsg` library. Are you linking it to **another** library? Please add this info, along with the **specific** error messages to your question post.

Comment: thank you. I added the complete cmake file and qmake file for future reference.